# Unexpected results with conditionals inside template part

Tags: page-template, conditional-tags, get-template-part

**Scenario:** I have a template part `loop-product.php` which i am calling from `home.php`, `taxonomy.php` and a page template `template-products.php`. Inside that template part `loop-product.php` file i am setting the number of columns by checking [`is_home()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home) conditionals.

**Problem:**
The conditional works fine for homepage, taxonomy page but its still set on the page template. On the product item i have added a class `columns-$cols` so you can check it on the site. Its showing `columns-4` on the product template page where it suppose to show `columns-3`.

```
<?php
    $j = 1;
    if(is_home()){
        $cols = 4;
    }else{
        $cols = 3;
    }
    if(have_posts()):while(have_posts()):the_post();

        // getting thumbnail image here 
    ?>

            <div class="product-item <?php echo 'columns-'.$cols ?>" <?php if($j%$cols == 0){ echo 'style="margin-right:0;"'; } ?>>
              <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <span class="product-img">
                    <img src="<?php echo $img[0]; ?>" width="100" height="75" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                </span>
                <span class="desc">
                    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <?php
                    if($price): ?>
                    <span class="price">Price: <?php echo $price; ?> BDT</span>
                <?php endif; ?>                    

                     </span>
                </a>
             </div>
             <?php if($j%$cols == 0){ echo '<div class="clear"></div>'; } ?>

             <?php $j++; endwhile; endif; ?>

                <div class="clear"></div>
```

Check the site here http://computercarebd.com/ Appreciate your time. Thanks!

Page template code: http://pastebin.com/CzRgzzVF

Comment: Have you changed the reading options the in the admin about the first page showing something else but the normal home?

Comment: @Kevin: No its a normal homepage. No static page..

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the body class to target these elements with CSS. You could do something like the following and make your PHP a little cleaner.

```
.product-item{width:33%;}
.home .product-item{width:25%;}
```

Comment: Along the same lines, since you are using custom template files anyway, why not just define `$cols` explicitly in each template file, rather than defining it in the template-part file? e.g. just define `$cols = 3` immediately before calling `get_template_part( 'loop', 'products' )`.

Comment: @ChipBennett: tried that but `$cols` is undefined inside the template part.

Comment: Globalize it, and call the global inside the template-part file?